# Flutter custom wave tab Clipper

Tags: flutter, dart, clipper

Can someone help me with this ClipPath in Flutter?

I can't make the wave Clip
[image].

Answer (score 0):

use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/custom_clippers

add `custom_clippers: ^2.0.0`to your pubspec.yaml